# Python subclassing causes IDLE to restart

Tags: python, class, subclass, python-idle

I found this issue in a long, complex script, but while debugging stripped it down to this very minimal form which still causes the same problem:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import(QMainWindow)

class Window(QMainWindow):
    pass
```

When I import this class through the IDLE interpreter, then try to instantiate the class with

```
w = Window()
```

the shell restarts with a "========== RESTART: Shell ===========" message.

These things fix the problem:

- Rewriting the code so that the Window class has no superclass:

  ```
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import(QMainWindow)

  class Window:
      pass
  ```
- Running the code outside of IDLE by double-clicking the file when it has an "if **name**=='main':" conditional added

These things do *not* fix the problem:

- Changing the name of the class
- Changing the class used as a super

The clincher is that when I go back and try to import/instantiate similarly subclassed classes from old scripts that worked fine in the past and haven't been touched in awhile, they now exhibit exactly the same problem.

So, as far as I can tell, I have an IDLE-specific problem that crashes/restarts the interpreter when it tries to instantiate any subclass, and which arose spontaneously where it wasn't present before.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: IDLE runs on Tkinter (a framework used to build GUIs). You're trying to create an instance of a window object in QT (a framework used to build GUIs). They both expect to be able to assume control of the interpreter with their own event loops and hooks - I'd be surprised if things didn't go *boom*.

Comment: When `Window` is subclassed from `QMainWindow`, `Window()` runs `QMainWindow.__init__`.  I suspect that is somehow clashing.  See if `QMainWindow()` does the same.  What exact x.y.z Python version?  Were old scripts run with a different version?  Or did change happen with same version?  What happens if you edit Lib/idlelib/run.py and comment out `handle_tk_events()`, about line 140 in the `main` function?

Comment: @NinjaPuppy  While IDLE is based on tk, it usually runs user code in a separate process that does not involve tk directly, except for a periodic call to `tcl.eval("update")` wrapped as `handle_tk`.  When there are no tk widgets, this is supposed to be a null operation.  And apparently has been harmless before.  But maybe the latest version of tcl/tk changed this.  Or maybe something changed in Python.  Or even in QT5 or PyQT5.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy thanks for info.

Comment: When you say 'changing class used as a super', do you mean other QT classes or non-QT classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help - as far as I can tell, there was in fact a clash between tkinter and Qt. A reinstall of my Python environment seems to have taken care of the problem!